# Wanted: The Very Topographic Map WITH Building Footprints The National Map Viewer Displays as Default

Tags: qgis, usgs, geospatial-pdf

I have been trying for 5 solid days to acquire building footprints from USGS topographic maps THAT I KNOW EXIST: I can SEE them on the very topo map which is displayed BY DEFAULT at The National Map viewer:
https://apps.nationalmap.gov/viewer/

I have been frustrated in my attempt to download THAT VERY map--the one that I'm actually looking at.

What is offered, after the search for locale (Mazomanie quadrangle) downloads in GeoPDF and GeoTIFF format, neither of which contains the building footprints.

I have been able to download the .pdf, extract information about the LAYERS inside it[1], and extract the most likely looking one[2], Structures, load that into QGIS3, and see that it is only sparsely populated with "public" structures, again, UNLIKE what I see before downloading.

I've since found building footprints at OpenStreetMap, but I feel certain that they MUST be available from The National Map server, or elsewhere at USGS and I merely have a blind spot, possibly HUGE. (I have a nagging sense that I USED to be able to do this.)

Can anyone recognize and identify my problem?

[1] gdalinfo -mdd LAYERS downloaded.geo.pdf
[2] gdal_translate -of GTiff downloaded.geo.pdf extracted-structures.geo.tif --config  GDAL_PDF_LAYERS "Map_Frame.Structures"

Answer (score 4):

It's a tile service that you're seeing.

If you just want to visualise it in QGIS, open the Layer - Data Source Manager (Ctrl+L) XYZ tab, select  New and paste [https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSTopo/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}](https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSTopo/MapServer/tile/%7Bz%7D/%7By%7D/%7Bx%7D) into the URL field.

[image]

Or you can add it as an ArcGIS Rest Server using the URL https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSTopo/MapServer

[image]

Alternatively, it looks like the data is available from:

- [A national dataset of rasterized building footprints for the U.S.](https://data.usgs.gov/datacatalog/data/USGS:5e432002e4b0edb47be84652)
- [microsoft/USBuildingFootprints](https://github.com/Microsoft/USBuildingFootprints)

Comment: @quagmire Did this answer solve your issue? If it did, you may choose to [accept to mark the question as answered](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Or if not, please provide feedback so the answer can be improved and help you or future users with the same problem.